# How can I share the Ubuntu screen to Mac?

Tags: screen, mac, remote-x-session

I'd like to know how can I share my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS screen with a Mac OS X 10.8.2 machine.

Is there a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

For a quick and dirty way, you could install [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) on both machines. For something more elegant, consider using a VNC client on the Mac and a VNC server on the Ubuntu machine. See [the community documentation on VNC.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC)

Comment: Interesting Clive. But TeamViewer looks like need share a pass. Do you know a easy way to connect withou go to other computer and get some pass on the screen or askin the remote machine user pass?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a simple add-on or "app" called VNC Viewer that works nicely.  I tried it on my Mac from my Ubuntu Studio (13.04) machine using X11VNC Server and it worked nicely.  Everything was simple to install, and X11VNC Server is available from the Ubuntu Software Center.